# How to write unit test case for spring boot controller with POST endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, junit

Controller with POST endpoint is as below :

```
@PostMapping(/addstudentdata)
public StudentResponse addStudentData(@RequestBody StudentDetails studentDetails, HttpServletResponse resp){

.//some logic here
.
resp.setHeader("Cache-Control,"no-cache");
resp.setStatus(200);
.
.
.//some logic here

return studentResponse;
}
```

How to write a proper unit test case for this and pass a JWT token ?

Comment: Did you see these? https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/ https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing

Comment: Yes. But there is no explanation for POST mapping in the share link. and in the link I was getting error related to `ResultMatcher`  at this  step `this.mockMvc.perform(get("/greeting")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello, Mock")));`